# Conditional replacement of all occurrences of a variable?

Tags: expression-manipulation

I know there is functionality in Mathematica to perform replacements like:

```
x[a] d[a,b]/.y_[z_] d[z_,p_]->y[p]
```

Which naturally gives `x[b]` as a result. Now, I was wondering if there is a stronger generalization, such that:

```
x[a]Subscript[q,a]Superscript[m,a]d[a,b]/. y_ d[z_,p_]->(set all occurrences of z to p in y)
```

was done automatically and the result would be `x[b]Subscript[q,b]Superscript[m,b]`? What syntax should I use to achieve that? thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of but perhaps this can work for you:

```
x[a] Subscript[q, a] Superscript[m, a] d[a, b] /. 
 y_ d[z_, p_] :> (y /. z -> p) d[z, p]
```

Comment: Wow! It actually does work. I did not know you could stack those operators. Great, exactly what I needed.